# Develop custom admin panel with front user in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to implement a custom admin panel, which can add merchant and view reports. admin have different URL to login into the admin panel.
the merchant as frontend user has a login to their account and manage payment send an email etc. merchant can using the application on a subdomain.
can anyone help me to implement the solution?

Comment: This question is too broad for Stack Overflow. Please see: [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I want to add admin panel in application with different URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add separate admin panel in to your application, first of all you need to create different routes, views and controllers for admins. Then implement your logic that differentiate merchant from admin. You can start from there.